# Error when generating prisma: -- EACCES: permission denied, need to copy file

Tags: prisma

When I run `npx prisma generate`, I get the below error:

`Error: EACCES: permission denied, copyfile '/Users/<me>/.cache/prisma/master/1a2506facaf1a4727b7c26850735e88ec779dee9/darwin/libquery-engine' -> '/Users/<me>/<my-project>/node_modules/prisma/libquery_engine-darwin.dylib.node'`

I have re-cloned the project from Github source, but this error doesn't go away.
What I previously did is deleting the `node_modules` folder because I want to re-install it (this could be the problem).

Should I just delete the prisma inside of the `.cache`? I am not sure why I need to do the copy file command and how can I fix this issue?

Thanks so much in advance!

ps: full sequence of commands: sudo yarn install, start docker for postgres, then the prisma generate command above.

Answer (score 4):

The correct is:

```
chown -R node:node node_modules/.prisma
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

It seems like a permission error. You could fix it by changing the ownership of the node_modules/.prisma folder from the root to the default one in your docker container.

```
chown -R node_modules/.prisma node:node
```